# Identify hub / freehub body on Giant FCR 2 2008

Tags: hub, freehub, giant

The rear wheel bearings on my 2008 Giant FCR2 need replacing, and the freehub body is feeling a bit notchy, so while it's all in bits I'd like to be able to have the option of replacing.

I understand that this hub should be a Formula sealed bearing hub, according to the specs, but I can't see any identifying marks to indicate the model on the hub or freehub body apart from "HA" stamped on the body.
[image: Giant FCR2 2008 specification]

Can anybody identify this hub and body and/or suggest a compatible body replacement? (Click images for larger views.)

[image: Side view of freehub showing "H" "A" stamped on a spline]
[image: Oblique view of hub on the drive side]
[image: View of non-drive side of the hub]

Comment: I've just done a bit more disassembly... it's not a sealed bearing, it's cup and cone.

Comment: My experience with these is that you are wasting your time trying to make it smoother, they are not good hubs. It will provide a good excuse to buy a better wheel though. You don't need to spend a fortune to get considerably better performance!

Comment: @JoeK It does not take much effort to do a good cleaning and find out if things smooth out. "good" There are dozens of hubs more poorly made than this one. There are also many hubs that are of higher quality. Making it smoother may or may not have anything to do with how good it is and might have everything to do with a good cleaning.

Comment: @David you are right but generally these have so little grease from the factory that by the time they feel rough, the races and cones are ruined. Applying good grease from 0 miles makes them ok. On a bike like the giant, it's the worst hub you'll find but yes, worse hubs do exist!

Comment: I had it in bits today, and the drive side cup is pitted, so I packed new bearings and grease in there so it's at least rideable now. New wheelset is looking likely in the near future. Any recommendations on a reasonable upgrade from Alex Da22 rims gratefully received!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information from Giant, looking at the [hub models from Formula](https://www.formulahubs.com/product.php?t=2) it looks like an RB-32 or RB-32C

[image]

Comment: It's definitely a Shimano HG fitment, which looks more like the RB-32 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the bike is more than a dozen years old and has rim-brakes, it would be a good idea to check the state of the rims. Depending on the mileage of the bike they could easily have reached the safety limit and need replacing.

So a pair of new wheels may be an option.

Comment: Drive side cup is pitted, so it's definitely time for a new wheel, I think. I was only going to replace the freehub body if it was easy to do so, but the hub being in a poor state now means I'll look for a new wheelset